# How to run all the scripts found by find

Tags: linux, bash, find

I'm trying to find all the init scripts created for websphere.
I know all the scripts end up with -init, so the first part of the code is:

```
find /etc/rc.d/init.d -name "*-init"
```

Also, I need all the script that run on an specific path, so the second part would be

```
| grep -i "/opt/ibm"
```

Finally, I need help with the last part. I have found the scripts I need to run them with the stop argument.

```
find /etc/rc.d/init.d -name "*-init" | grep -i "/opt/ibm" | <<run script found with stop argument>>
```

How can I run the command found with find?

Comment: What do you mean "I need to run them with the stop argument"?

Comment: I need to add the stop argument when I run the command. Ej: was-dmgr-init stop/start/status

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you omit the 'find' and use grep directly you could do something like this:

```
grep -i "/opt/ibm" /etc/rc.d/init.d/* | sed 's/:.*/ stop/g' | sort -u | bash
```

- it uses grep directly, which adds the filename to the output: `filename:matched line`
- since you only need the filename and not the match, use sed to replace the ':' and the rest of the line with ' stop' (see the space before stop)
- use `sort -u` (make sure, to execute each script only once)
- Pipe the result into a shell

Comment: this works with a little change grep -i "/opt/ibm" /etc/rc.d/init.d/* | sed 's/:.*/ stop/g' | sort -u | bash
Remove the -init and leave only *

Comment: @radicaled, i edited my answer to the code that worked. Can you mark it as correct?

Answer (score 0):

Use a loop so that we are a little more careful while executing them:

```
#!/bin/bash

shopt -s globstar
for file in /etc/rc.d/init.d/**/*-init; do     # grab all -init scripts
  script=$(readlink -f "$file")                # grab the actual file in case of a symlink
  [[ -f $script ]]          || continue        # skip if not a regular file
  [[ $file = */opt/ibm/* ]] || continue        # not "/opt/ibm/", skip
  printf '%s\n' "Executing script '$script'"
  "$script" stop; exit_code=$?
  printf '%s\n' "Script '$script' finished with exit_code $exit_code"
done
```

Comment: Downvoter, please let me know what is wrong here so that I may be able to rectify it.

Comment: I'm not the downvoter - and I also find unexplained downvoting **extremely annoying**, but I think your `ibm` test is inverted. Have my  upvote though!

Comment: OP wants to skip all non-/opt/ibm/ scripts.  So, it is `|| continue`, right?

Comment: You may be right, but I understood OP wants to *find* all Websphere (which is IBM, I thought) rather than skip them. I don't know!